# wxpython wizard not found import error

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Hello whenever I try any of the code examples [like here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/01/27/wxpython-a-wizard-tutorial/) for WxPython I always get:

```
import wx.wizard
```

ImportError: No module named wizard

Any idea, a I missing a package, I tried updating WX many times but its latest version.

Comment: What's your wxpython version? wx.version()

Comment: What happens when you try to import wx.wizard directly in an interactive Python shell?

Answer (score 2):

If it is still relevant:
With wx.**version** = '4.0.1' following works:

```
from wx.adv import Wizard
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance using wxPython Phoenix?

If yes then 'wizard' has moved to wx.adv, so you need to do:

from wx.adv import wizard

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, the wxpython package was reworked and the modules in `wx.wizard` were moved to `wx.adv`. As such, `wx.wizard.Wizard`, is now `wx.adv.Wizard`, `wx.wizard.PyWizardPage` is now `wx.adv.WizardPage`, etc.

Documentation for `wx.adv` can be found here : https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.adv.1moduleindex.html